# Ubuntu: beamer not working

Tags: beamer, pdftex, ubuntu

I used to be a regular latex user but haven't touched it in the last two years due to being out of academia. So sorry for what might be a stupid question.

I want to create a beamer presentation. Here is what I start with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\title{Simple Beamer Class}   
\author{Sascha Frank} 
\date{\today} 

\frame{\titlepage} 

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents} 

\begin{frame}
hi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For compiling and executing, I use `pdflatex filename.tex` as I remember doing.

I am getting the following errors:

```
l.11 \documentclass
               {beamer}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \begin
           {document}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \title
           {Simple Beamer Class}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \author
            {Sascha Frank}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 \date
          {\today}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 \date{\today
                 }
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \frame
           {\titlepage}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \frame{\titlepage
                      }
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 \frame
           {\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 \frame{\frametitle
                       {Table of contents}\tableofcontents}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 ...metitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents
                                                  }
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.21 \begin
           {frame}
? 
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] )</usr/share/texlive/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on presentation.pdf (1 page, 15084 bytes).
```

I have installed the `texlive` package from ubuntu's apt. Ubuntu tells me that `latex-beamer`, (and dependencies `pgf` `latex-xcolor` etc) are already installed. A pdf is produced but its just the text with no slides.

Comment: I suggest you stick to `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` and drop the `\frame` command. I'd also write the `\title`, `\author` and `\date` in the preamble.

Comment: @Dox I made those changes, still the pdflatex compiler is giving me an error `undefined control sequence` on every single line command.

Comment: Could you post the result of the command (in the terminal) `locate beamer | grep cls`?

Comment: Your code works fine in my machine. Please check that your installation is Ok.

Comment: @Dox no `cls` is grepped. I am dumping the output for `locate beamer` here: http://pastebin.com/pb9Pqajf

Comment: So your installation includes no beamer! X-) It is crazy. A not-so-clever advise would be to install the complete set of texlive packages using `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`.... Do not try it if your internet connection is slow!!!

Comment: off-topic comment (I admit it ;-)) `LaTeX` is used outside academia as well ;-)

Comment: @Dox yeah, I installed `texlive` as `texlive-full` would be way too big. texlive basic is supposed to have beamer but I cannot run it. Trying to install it separately it tells me that latex-beamer is already the newest version.

Comment: @Dox the recommend way is given in [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: Did you have a look in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer` for `beamer.cls`? If you have installed texlive today, there is perhaps no `updatedb` run for locate so far, so it can be found with `locate`. Perhaps you have to update the `TeX` hash tables. Try as root user: `texconfig rehash`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer there is a `beamer.cls` in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I ran a `sudo texconfig rehash` but I get the same errors.

Comment: @yayu: I wonder a little bit about `beamer/base`, since this is not the case for my distribution (I just checked the very old texlive2012, 2013 and the fresh 2014 version)

Comment: Does `kpsewhich beamer.cls` say anything useful?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `tex --version` gives me `TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer kspewhich returns  `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamer.cls`

Comment: Why does it say documentclass is line 11? What are the prior ten lines?

Comment: @JimHefferon those were `%` comments :) I have removed them and shared everything, including the log here: http://pastebin.com/5N98AvrW

Comment: @yayu: Did you really run `pdflatex presentation`? The log file rather hints to `pdftex presentation`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am stupid. Yes, that was the problem. Please post this as an answer. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @yayu: Added the answer, just to `close`. So, this was a heavy run ;-) I wish, I had looked into the log file earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is solved, it was just the wrong usage of `pdftex` which does not know of `\documentclass` command.

The error is not connected directly to Ubuntu but can occur on any operating system.

In order to compile `beamer` it is necessary to use `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead.

For example call on commandline or corresponding menu command/button in a TeX editor

```
pdflatex foo
```